# Is there a way to show the status bar in Adobe Reader in Reading Mode?

Tags: adb, 9.0-pie, adobe-reader

Adobe Reader has a "Reading Mode" that is very nice for reading books and other documents but unfortunately, it hides the status bar on my Essential Phone.

This phone has a notch so when the status bar is hidden, instead of disappearing completely, it becomes blank instead. I'd rather see my notifications and especially the clock at all times.

I tried with adb:

```
settings put global policy_control immersive.status=-com.adobe.reader
```

but it still didn't force it, the status area remains blank :(

Is there some sort of other adb command that can override this application control to show the notification area as usual, around the notch?